# Twitter api statuses/destroy api 401 error

Tags: delphi, oauth, twitter, delphi-7, indy

I'm authenticating with OAuth getting my request token, authorizing, doing POST to get the AccessToken and then pulling my user_timeline.xml

At this point I try and call the destroy api on a particular status id and it returns a 401 unauthorized.

I am able to take the url and the parameters out and call this through Fiddler2 and it works, but using it in a Delphi app with Indy V10 component, doing a POST it's giving this 401 still.

What can I be missing?

Thanks,
david

If I can figure this out this app is good to go, very frustrating.
Please help!

Comment: Any body from TeamB help with the Indy V10 Component Post ? Maybe I'm not passing my parameters in correctly ?

Comment: looks like when I use fiddler2 to try and trap the issue it's NEVER calling the POST on the destroy.  I never see the traffic.  However the POST for the authorize call worked fine.                     "POST http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms"       HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 13 Nov 2010 00:59:08 GMT
Server: hi
Status: 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Finally ran a .NET version of code, ran Fiddler2 to see what it did and noticed the Authorization Header. I then had to find a reference to this in regards to the Indy Components to figure it out. You have to add CustomHeaders with a specific format.

Comment: Indy's `TIdHTTP` component natively supports sending a `Authorization` request header, but it is dependant on `TIdAuthentication`-derived classes, and Indy does not have one for OAuth yet (it is on the todo list for Indy 11).  So yes, you need to use the `CustomHeaders` property to send a custom `Authentication` header for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try my implementation with ICS, supports Unicode as well

http://eden.fm/2011/02/27/twitter-library-for-delphi/